# Conditionally selecting the most recent occurrence of a variable?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a variable called "Effort", a variable called ID, and ID2. One ID has many ID2's. So I want to know when hovering over a bar chart what the most recent Effort was per ID.

Here are the two attempts I have made which did not work:

LOOKUP(ATTR([Effort]), Last() + 0)

IF(LAST([Effort])) == 0 THEN([Effort]) END

I was leaning towards the first one working, but it didn't seem to do what I was requiring correctly.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you indentify the most recent? do you have a date field for your data?

Comment: One hint. The function Max() works with dates as well as numbers and strings.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore That worked for me. Thank you again.